How read the text from the QML component in the Apium test?
I'm trying to write the simplest UI tests for an Android application(qt) with a QML interface.
In QML components, I set properties via the Accessible object. (qml code at the end)
The Appium test is implemented according to the instructions:

appium server, UiAutomator2 driver, requirements
write a test (js)

I have configured the startup parameters so that the application under test runs on AVD (android virtual device)
When I run the test, the application under test runs successfully on AVD, the interface is displayed.
What works fine in the test:

getting elements using locators
const passwordInput = await driver.$('~PasswordInput');

getting information about the coordinates of an element
await passwordInput.getLocation()
await passwordInput.getSize()

clicking on an element.
await applyButton.click()


But none of the methods for getting text data from an element works:
await passwordInput.getText()             // EMPTY RESULT
await passwordInput.getAttribute('text')  // EMPTY RESULT
await passwordInput.getProperty('text')   // ERROR
await passwordInput.getValue()            // ERROR

Is it possible to read the text of the QML component from the appium test?
=====================================================
Capability Set:
{
  "platformName"          : "Android",
  "appium:platformVersion": "14",
  "appium:deviceName"     : "emulator-XXXX",
  "appium:app"            : "C:/temp/androidtestapp.apk",
  "appium:automationName" : "UiAutomator2"
}

part of main.qml:
TextField {
    id                      : idPasswordInput
    focus                   : true
    Layout.fillWidth        : true
    objectName              : "PasswordInputName"
    text                    : "enter password..."
    Accessible.role         : Accessible.EditableText
    Accessible.name         : "PasswordInput"
    Accessible.description  : "PasswordInput description"
    Accessible.focusable    : true
    Accessible.ignored      : false

    Keys.onPressed: (event)=> {
        console.log("PasswordInput key:", event.key, "/", event.text);
    }
}

Running the test
node C:\temp\test.js

used:

Qt 6.7.2
appium, UiAutomator2, webdriverio - latest versions

